# Ruby win32-api GetFocus and GetWindowText

Tags: ruby, winapi

I'm trying to find a way to get the current window's text. 
So using the win32-api gem I wrote this code using some help from [this page](https://bitbucket.org/thomthom/tt-library-2/src/5fb374db1bd1/TT_Lib2/win32.rb)

```
require 'win32/api'
include Win32
hWnd = GetActiveWindow = API.new('GetActiveWindow', 'V', 'L', 'user32').call
GetWindowText       = API.new('GetWindowText', 'LPI', 'I', 'user32')
GetWindowTextLength = API.new('GetWindowTextLength', 'L', 'I', 'user32')
buf_len = GetWindowTextLength.call(hwnd)
str = ' ' * (buf_len + 1)
# Retreive the text.
result = GetWindowText.call(hwnd, str, str.length)
puts str.strip
```

The output is just an empty string because buf_len is always calculated as 0 due to hwnd being set as 0.
I can't figure out why the hwnd returned is always just a 0.

Comment: The MSDN states _"The return value is the handle to the active window attached to the **calling thread**'s message queue. Otherwise, the return value is NULL."_ Are you calling this from the correct thread, i.e. the thread that owns the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously commented `GetActiveWindow` will only retrieve the window attached to the calling thread's message queue.  If you want to get a handle to the window that the user is currently regardless of what process it is running in try calling [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) rather than `GetActiveWindow`.

> Retrieves a handle to the foreground window (the window with which the user is currently working).

Comment: I didn't realize how I missed that. Thanks a lot to both you and Tim!